# Builds failing in TFS due to missing visual studio version

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to build my application through tfs and it keeps failed due to the platform toolset I'm targeting not being installed on the server.

My full error message is

```
Visual Studio version '15.0' not found. Looking for the latest version.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets (57, 5)
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): Error MSB8020: The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141 build tools. Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".
```

I'm selecting Visual Studio 2017 in my build definition. What do I need to do to configure this server properly so it can build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the MsBuild task it may be enough to just install the build tools. Launch the [Visual Studio 2017 Build tools installer](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) on the build server and install at least "Msbuild" and the "CPP" packages.

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/

If you're depending on the Visual Studio task and some of the packages that aren't installed by the build tools, you'll need to install Visual Studio 2017 on the build server.

Comment: Installing Visual Studio will indeed solve the problem. It's a bit of an aggravation, but a lot easier than trying to get all the libraries needed in the right place by hand.